# Поиск индекса элемента

Tags: массивы, c++

Компилятор выдает ошибку: индекс имеет нецелый тип. Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T,class B>
B find (T*array,T value, B size)
{ 
    for (B j = 0; j<size;j++)
        if(array[j] == value)
            return j;
        return static_cast<B>(-1);
}
int intARR[] = {1,3,5,6,7,8};
int in = 6;
double doubARR[] = {1.9,2.0,4.0};
double dou = 5.0;
void main ()
{ 
    cout<<"element 6 v intARR imeet index = "<<find(intARR,in,6)<<endl;
    cout<<"element 5.0 v doubARR imeet index = "<<find(doubARR,dou,3.0)<<endl;
    system ("PAUSE");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Вполне логично - ошибка в строке:

```
cout<<"element 5.0 v doubARR imeet index = "<<find(doubARR,dou,3.0)<<endl;
```

Последний аргумент - 3.0 - вещественный, поэтому B == double. Что и приводит к ошибке.

В целом я не вижу никакой необходимости в типе B. Это же индекс.

С другой стороны, даже логически понятно, что размер массива не может быть вещественным. Классическое школьное "два с половиной землекопа".

Минимально исправленный вариант кода:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
int find (T*array,T value, int size)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j<size;j++)
        if(array[j] == value)
            return j;
        return -1;
}
int intARR[] = {1,3,5,6,7,8};
int in = 6;
double doubARR[] = {1.9,2.0,4.0};
double dou = 5.0;
int main ()
{ 
    cout<<"element 6 v intARR imeet index = "<<find(intARR,in,6)<<endl;
    cout<<"element 3 v doubARR imeet index = "<<find(doubARR,dou,3)<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Добавлю к ответу уважаемого @KoVadim, что выбранный алгоритм поиска индекса не самый лучший, а, думаю, самый худший.